# Является ли строка палиндромом

Tags: c++, строки, visual-studio-2010

По заданию я должен разработать функцию, которая проверяет является ли строка палиндромом или нет. Строка может содержать пунктуацию и пробелы. Например: “Madam,I’m Adam”.По-сути я пытаюсь упростить данную строку до  “madamimadam”.

Вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

bool isPal(const string &);

int main()
{
    string input;
    cout << "Enter a string to check if this is a palindrome: ";
    getline(cin, input);
    if (isPal(input))
        cout << "Yes, this is the palindrome." << endl;
    else
        cout << "No, it's not." << endl;
    return 0;
}

bool isPal(const string & st)
{
    string temp = st;
    temp.erase(remove_if(temp.begin(), temp.end(), isspace), temp.end());
    temp.erase(remove_if(temp.begin(), temp.end(), ispunct), temp.end());
    if ( temp == string(temp.rbegin(), temp.rend()))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Простые слова типа otto функция выдает правильно, но с более сложными строками не получается. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так.

Comment: А зачем так сложно? Не проще просто идти с двух концов, игнорируя ненужное?

Comment: tolower is missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не хотите что-то вроде такого?

```
bool isPal(const string & st)
{
    for(auto b = st.begin(), e = st.end()-1; b < e; ++b, --e)
    {
        while(!isalnum(*b)) ++b;
        while(!isalnum(*e)) --e;
        if (toupper(*b) != toupper(*e)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Имеет смысл добавить защиту от дурака - пустые строки, только из пунктуаций и т.п.

Да, для VC++ 2010 замените `auto` на `string::const_iterator`.

Comment: А разве пустая строка - не палиндром? Вроде всё и так хорошо.

Comment: Хотя стоп. Понял. В цикле нет проверки выхода за границы строки. Кстати, это баг... Или нет... Запутался...

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну, например, `"....."` будет не палиндромом. И вообще может выскочить за границы... Это баг на пустой строке, потому я и написал, что имеет смысл дописать проверки.

Answer (score 1):

Можно решить задачу и таким образом:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void IsPalindrome(string s)
{
    string word ; // переменная для хранения слова наоборот
    // нужно как-то понять, является ли s палиндромом
    // Пересобираем слово с конца в начало
    for(int i = s.size()-1; i >= 0; i-- )
    {
        word = word + s[i];
        //cout << a << endl;
    }
    if(s == word) { cout << "1" << endl; }
    else { cout << "0" << endl; }
}

int main() 
{
    IsPalindrome("ara"s);
    IsPalindrome("deer"s);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Тоже когда-то решал такую задачу. Получилось так:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    if (equal(s.begin(), s.begin() + s.size()/2, s.rbegin())) {
        cout << "is a palindrome" << endl;

    } else {
        cout << "is not a palindrome" << endl;
    }
}
```