# Вызвано исключение: нарушение для чтения. р1 было nullptr. С++

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы

Задание звучит так: Дан текстовый файл. Группы символов, разделённые пробелами,будем называть словами. Удалить из файла все слова,не являющимися палиндромами(слова,которые читаются справа налево и слева направо одинаково). Код прилагается. ошибку написал

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

struct LIST
{
    string n; // ИНФОРМАЦИОННОЕ ПОЛЕ
    LIST *next; // УКАЗАТЕЛЬ НА СЛЕДУЮЩИЙ ЭЛЕМЕНТ СПИСКА
};
LIST *del(LIST *lst)
{
    int i, z = 0;
    LIST *p1 = lst, *p2 = p1->next, *prev = lst;
    string k;
    while (p1)
    {
        k = p1->n;
        for (i = 0; i < k.length() / 2; i++) // НАЧАЛО ПРОВЕРКИ
                                                                    //ОЧЕРЕДНОГО СЛОВА НА ПОЛИНДРОМ
        {
            if (k[i] != k[k.length() - 1 - i])
            {
                z++;
            }
        } // КОНЕЦ ПРОВЕРКИ ОЧЕРЕДНОГО СЛОВА НА
                                                              //ПОЛИНДРОМ
        if (z)
        {
            delete p1;
            if (p1 == lst)
            {
                lst = p2;
                prev = lst;
                p1 = lst;
            }
            else
            {
                prev->next = p2;
                p1 = prev;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            prev = p1; // ЕСЛИ ТЕКУЩИЙ ЭЛЕМЕНТ НЕ УДАЛЯЛСЯ,
                                                                //ТО ОН СТАНОВИТСЯ ПРЕДЫДУЩИМ
        }
        if (p1 != p2) // ЕСЛИ УДАЛЯЛАСЬ НЕ ГОЛОВА СПИСКА, ТО p1
                                                                      //ПЕРЕМЕЩАЕТСЯ ВПЕРЕД
        {
            p1 = p1->next;
        }
        if (p2)              // ЕСЛИ НЕ ДОСТИГНУТ КОНЕЦ СПИСКА, ТО p2
                                                                       //ПЕРЕМЕЩАЕТСЯ ДАЛЬШЕ
        {
            p2 = p2->next;
        }
        z = 0;
    }
    return lst;
}

void sort(LIST *lst);
LIST *del(LIST *lst);
int main()
{
    LIST *lst = NULL; // УКАЗАТЕЛЬ ДЛЯ ХРАНЕНИЯ ГОЛОВЫ СПИСКА
    LIST *p1, *p2, *prev; // ВСПОМОГАТЕЛЬНЫЕ УКАЗАТЕЛИ
    string k; // ВСПОМОГАТЕЛЬНАЯ ПЕРЕМЕННАЯ ДЛЯ ХРАНЕНИЯ
                //ВВОДИМЫХ СТРОК
    int i, j, z = 0;
    ifstream f("D:\Me\1.txt");
    if (f)
    {
        f >> k;
        lst = new LIST; // ВЫДЕЛЕНИЕ ПАМЯТИ ПОД ГОЛОВУ СПИСКА
        lst->n = k; // ЗАПОЛНЕНИЕ ИНФОРМАЦИОННОГО ПОЛЯ
        p1 = lst; // ЗАНОСИМ АДРЕС ГОЛОВЫ СПИСКА В
                    //ВСПОМОГАТЕЛЬНЫЙ УКАЗАТЕЛЬ
        while (!f.eof())
        {
            f >> k;
            p1->next = new LIST; // СОЗДАЕМ НОВЫЙ ЭЛЕМЕНТ
            p1 = p1->next; // p ТЕПЕРЬ ССЫЛАЕТСЯ НА СОЗДАННЫЙ УКАЗАТЕЛЬ
            p1->n = k; // ЗАПОЛНЕНИЕ ИНФОРМАЦИОННОГО ПОЛЯ
        }
        p1->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error to open file f";
    }
    f.close();
    p1 = del(lst);
    ofstream f1("D:\Me\1.txt");
    if (f1)
    {
        while (p1 != NULL)
        {
            k = p1->n;
            f1 << k << " ";
            p1 = p1->next;
        }
    }
    f1.close();
    system("pause");
}
```

тут выдаёт исключение:

```
LIST *p1 = lst, *p2 = p1->next, *prev = lst;
```

Comment: Вопросы про поиск палиндромов уже были не один раз. Например, [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/715192/312941)

Comment: @Tocic если вы не поняли,задача заключается не в поиске палиндрома,а в работе с файлом. и ошибка тоже, не в поиске палиндрома

Comment: Как то код выглядит излешне переусложненным. Зачем то изобретаются списки (но есть же стандартный std::list), файл закрывается вручную (а как же RAII), Также, если не удалось открыть файл, то просто ругаемся и идем дальше... И последнее, вот эти две строки кода ` delete p1;  if (p1 == lst)` -  Написать то так можно, то только это немного странно.

Comment: @СOM тогда почитайте [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Попробуйте так: `LIST *p1 = lst, *p2 = lst->next, *prev = lst;`.

Comment: @DmitryEgorenkov Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения.
lst было nullptr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что файл не открывается, потому что путь должен выглядеть так: `"D:\\Me\\1.txt"`. Соответственно, `del(lst)` вызывается для `lst == nullptr`.

Comment: Удивительно,так и есть,спасибо