# Является ли число (строка) полиндромом?

Tags: sqlite

Прежде, чем задать вопрос, поискал по SO и нашёл [эту тему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/715192/%d0%af%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bc). Но мой вопрос не по C++, а по SQLite. Можно ли средствами сабжа, без каких-либо сторонних средств, сделать подобные вычисления?

Answer (score 0):

Нет, невозможно. причина - **SQLite** не самостоятельная база данных, она **не существует в виде "запущенного" процесса отдельно от вашего приложения**. Так что без сторонних средств(например "приложения" которое будет делать запросы) - это невозможно.

Если речь идет о проверке строки с помощью SQL запросов - то это возможно, вопрос лишь в количестве и сложности запроса(запросов) для проверки.